# tranforming RxJS Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I use angularFirestore to query on firebase and I want join data from multiple documents using the DocumentReference.

The first operator map in the pipe return an array of IOrderModelTable, the second operator, i.e, the switchMap iterate over array an for each element use the id contained in each element to query data in other table.

The problem is that in the swithMap I obtain an array of observable due to anidated map operators. How I can obtain an array of IOrderModelTable and then return an observable of this array.

The code is:

```
getDataTableOperatorsFromDB(): Observable<IOrderModelTable[]> {
  const observable = this.tableOperatorsCollectionsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as IOrdersModelDatabase;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;

        data.ot = id;
        return data;
      });
    }),
    switchMap(data => {
      const result = data.map(element => {
        return this.afs.collection('Orders/').doc(element.orderNumberReference.id).valueChanges().pipe(map(order => {
          return {
            otNumber: element.ot,
            clientName: '',
            clientReference: order.clientReference,
            id: element.orderNumberReference,
          };
        }));
      });

      // Result must be an IOrderModelTable[] but is a Observable<IOrderModelTable>[]

      return of(result);
    })
  );
```

Comment: When you use `switchMap`, you are required to output an observable. So you can either replace switchMap with another operator (like map, concat etc.).Or, you can  transform your observable emissions into a list, use `toArray()` for this sake. VERY IMPORTANT : If your observable does not terminate, toArray won't work. I'm not sure to understand your problem very well though, a bit of explanation would help on 'why use switchMap', or "does your observable emit several times, or just once" ?

Comment: @madjaoue The observable never complete and emit an unique array with all the documents from firebase, I want to transform that array making queries to other documents for each element. Let's say the observable return an array of object, each object containing a order number and a id of the client, i need obtain the name of the client, for it I use the id, and combine with the order number, so that i have an array of object each object containing a client name and order number.

Comment: I posted an answer, can you try it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [to Array](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/toArray.js.html) operator to transform a stream to an array, but make sure your stream will end.
The trick is to choose the right stream.

For you problem, the *natural* source would be the list received by your first call. In a schematic way I can put it , you get a list of ids, that you transform into a list of augmented information :

first input `...snapshopChanges()`:

> ----[A, B, C]------>

each element is transformed through `...valueChanges()`:

> -------Call A -------------DataA-------->
>
> -------Call B ------------------------DataB----->
>
> -------Call C --------------------DataC----->

Then reduced using `toArray()` to :

> ----------------------------------------------[DataA, DataC, DataB]-------->

**Code**:

```
getDataTableOperatorsFromDB(): Observable<IOrderModelTable[]> { {
  return this.tableOperatorsCollectionsRef.snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions => {
        from(data).pipe(
          map(action => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as IOrdersModelDatabase;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            data.ot = id;
            return data;
          }),
          mergeMap(element => {
            return this.afs.collection('Orders/').doc(element.orderNumberReference.id).valueChanges().pipe(
              map(order => {
                return {
                  otNumber: element.ot,
                  clientName: '',
                  clientReference: order.clientReference,
                  id: element.orderNumberReference,
                };
              })
            );
          }),
          toArray()
        );
         
      })
    )
}
```

Important : I replaced `switchMap` by `mergeMap`, otherwise some information could be thrown away.

Comment: Since switchMap returns an observable, why can’t he just subscribe to the result and return it

Comment: @Pari Baker If you are talking about his code, his function returns a list of observables, something like `[Observable1, Observable2, Observable3,...]`. So the way he would use his function is `myfunction.subscribe( observables => observables.forEach( observable=> observable.subscribe(element=> ...))`. This is a bad idea for so many levels. If he has a list of 1000 elements, he would have to create 1000 Observables + subscribe to every one of them. Also, concatenating the 1000 subscriptions can be tricky for race conditions. 
The idea is : use the right operator, and the least effort...

Answer (score 1):

@madjaoue 
You're right, mergeMap is the correct operator in this case because with switchMap for each event emitted the inner observable is destroyed so in the subscribe you only get the final event emitted, i.e, the last row. This observable is long lived, never complete, so also use the operator take with the length of the actions which is the array that contains the list of documents.

Thank you very much for the help. :D

```
getDataTableOperatorsFromDB(): Observable<IOrderModelTable[]> {
    const observable = this.tableOperatorsCollectionsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      switchMap(actions => {
        return from(actions).pipe(
          mergeMap(action => {
            console.log(action);
            const data = action.payload.doc.data() as IOrdersModelDatabase;
            const otNumber = action.payload.doc.id;
            return this.afs.collection('Orders/').doc(data.orderNumberReference.id).valueChanges().pipe(map(order => {
              return {
                otNumber: otNumber,
                clientName: '',
                clientReference: order.clientReference,
                id: data.orderNumberReference,
              };
            }));
          }),
          mergeMap(order => {
            console.log(order);
            return this.afs.collection('Clients/').doc(order.clientReference.id).valueChanges().pipe(map(client => {
              return {
                otNumber: order.otNumber,
                clientName: client.name,
                clientReference: order.clientReference,
                id: order.id,
              };
            }));
          }),
          take(actions.length),
          toArray(),
          tap(console.log),
        );
      }),
```